# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Error on containerazing .Net Core 7 image on Docker

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize an asp .net core 7 image but when i run docker run command I get this Error message

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ./<backend-folder-name>/<backend-project-name>.csproj

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

**This is Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
EXPOSE 81
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--project", "./<backend-folder-name>/<backend-project-name>.csproj"]
```

**This is the run command**

```
docker run -p 81:81 --network <network-name> --name <container-name> -v <volume-name>:/app/data <image-name>
```

I don't know why I got that message. I'm pretty sure the location and name of the .csproj file are also correct

I tried to change location but that didn't work. I don't know what to do at the moment.

Comment: In the ENTRYPOINT statement in the Dockerfile, you're supposed to change `<backend-folder-name>/<backend-project-name>` to the path and filename of the csproj file.

Comment: /root/<sub-folder>/<project-folder>/<<backend-project-name>.csproj you mean like that? I am pretty sure that .csproj file name is correct bu this does not work as well

Comment: I would recommend running the container interactively and verifying the path of the project file by listing directory contents. To run container: `docker run --rm -it <image-name>`. The commands for listing directory contents vary by OS. It's not clear whether you're targeting Linux or Windows.